# MYSQL INSERT not working in php()

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

Here's the code:

```
    <html>

    <body>

    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","moviek5q_arka","******");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    $pizza  = "Age
    Anger
    Architecture
    Art 
    Beauty
    Birthday
    Business
    Car
    Change
    Computers
    Dad
    Dating
    Death
    Design
    Diet
    Dreams
    Education
    Environmental
    Equality
    Experience
    Faith
    Family
    Finance
    Fitness
    Food
    Forgiveness
    Friendship 
    Funny
    Gardening
    Government
    Graduation
    Happiness
    Health
    History
    Home
    Humor
    Imagination
    Inspirational
    Intelligence
    Leadership
    Legal
    Life 
    Love 
    Marriage
    Medical
    Men
    Mom
    Money
    Motivational 
    Movies
    Music
    Nature
    Parenting
    Patriotism
    Peace
    Pet
    Poetry
    Politics
    Power
    Religion
    Science
    Society
    Sports
    Success 
    Technology
    Teen
    Time
    Travel
    Trust
    War
    Wedding
    Wisdom 
    Women
    Work
    ";
    $pieces = explode("\n", $pizza);
    $i=0;

    $a=mysql_select_db("moviek5q_Quote", $con);
    if(!$a) echo"Error";

    for($i=8;$i<75;$i++) {


    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO moviek5q_Quote.Categories (Key, Name)
    VALUES
    (NULL,'$pieces[$i]')");
    if(!$sql) {die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}

    }

    mysql_close($con);

    echo "done";
    ?>

    </body>

</html>
```

But running the script gives the error:

> Could not connect: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Key, Name) VALUES (NULL,'Change')' at line 1

Comment: is connection is established ?

Comment: echo the sql string for us please

Comment: query in loop... its worst idea to use

Comment: you know what it mean ? `for($i=8;$i<75;$i++) {` 67query in a single page load ... it will reduce your performance .. and create huge load on server

Comment: The bug is correctly pointed out by Shaquin, The connection was established.
@NullPointer I am new in MySQL, so i just made a php page for uploading 75 entries into a database.This php page will not be loaded anytime later! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your field name `Key` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and so the query will fail. You can use backticks to correct it:

```sql
INSERT INTO moviek5q_Quote.Categories (`Key`, Name)
```

Answer (score 4):

`Key` is a reserved keyword that is why it is crashing. Either change column name or put it in quotes (`).

e.g.

```
$sql = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO moviek5q_Quote.Categories (`Key`, Name)
VALUES
(NULL, '$pieces[$i]')" );
```

For a full list of reserved keywords check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Thanks, Changing Column Name worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Just a tip, try to use PDO or MySQLi, `mysql_` code is now deprecated and may not be available in the future.

- [PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo)
- [MySQLi](http://php.net/book.mysqli)

Comment: Yes, `mysql` extension is quite old is not recommended.